# jquery is not work for every href element

Tags: php, jquery, css

1. when first "read more" href click, div changed.first click it span and when second click it shrink.
2. But it is not work for other href element
3. how to solve this problem.please help me.

   ```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#more').click(function(){
               var toggleheight = $("#readmore").height() == 500 ? "100px" : "500px";
                     $('#readmore').animate({ height: toggleheight });
                     });
              });

        </script>
   ```
4. here is the php code

   ```
        <?php
         mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
         $set_news=mysql_query("SELECT solution_date,Category,solution FROM solution ORDER BY solution_date DESC LIMIT 10",$connection);
           if(!$set_news){
           die("database query failed".mysql_error()); 
                           }

                           for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++) {
                           $rowofnews=mysql_fetch_array($set_news);

                           $category=$rowofnews['Category'];
                           $solution=$rowofnews['solution'];

                           echo ('<li>');
                           echo ('<div id="readmore"');
                           echo('<h2>');
                           echo $category;
                           echo('</h2><p>');
                           echo $solution;
                           echo('</p></div>');
                           echo('<p><span><a href="#" class="more" id="more">Read More</a></span></p></li>');
                           }
           ?>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

ID's are unique, duplicate ID is not allowed refer http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/ for more details.

and try chnaging your script to

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.more').on('click', function(){
         var toggleheight = $(".readmore").height() === 500 ? "100px" : "500px";
            $('.readmore').stop().animate({ height: toggleheight });
            });
       });
 </script>
```

[jQuery.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) stops currently-running animation.

Comment: after I added class for div then all the div got span when a button clicked.stop() function is not working.

Comment: Did you changed the css selector with #more .more and #readmore to .readmore

Comment: Made a demo on [jsFiddle demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/vineethkrishnan007/Z9R8W/), It is not necessary to give everything as class if your element is unique give it id instead. in this demo i have reference which box is to expand and shrink with **data** attribute.
Second demo is at [jsFiddle demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/vineethkrishnan007/qF9ss/) more link placed inside the box so that it can refer to parent so there is no additional reference to which box is to animate.
Does this help you to clear your idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to select multiple elements, you shouldn't use ID's, you should select by `class`, like this:

```
$('.more').on("click", function(){
```

Comment: only first read more href is working.others are not working for this.